# Java CDI and private constructors

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton

I have a singleton class that has a private default constructor and a public instance-getter like follows:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass INSTANCE = new MyClass();

    private MyClass() {}

    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use CDI to enable dependency injection for this class, but also tell the container to use the value returned from the getInstance() method? Not every application accessing the class will be in a servlet container so the instance-getting method will still need to used in those situations.

Comment: Do you use Spring?

Comment: Not on this app

Comment: When do you get @Model annotation (library)?

Comment: Create a bean with `@Named` annotation, having method `MyClass getMyClass() { return MyClass.INSTANCE; }`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use CDI. Try the following:

```
@ApplicationScoped 
@Named //necessary only if you want to refer to by name binding on JSF
public class MyClass {
    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCreate() {
        System.out.println("Object created");
    }
}
```

This way you will have one @Inject -able CDI bean for the whole application. Essentially a Singleton for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a producer as well

```
@Produces @ApplicationScoped
private static MyClass INSTANCE = new MyClass();
```

Then its available as a bean when you `@Inject MyClass myClass` but you should really switch it to be a full managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

There is a @Singleton stereotype available in CDI. Use this, instead of emulating this behavior with producers or any other ways.

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class MyClass {
@Inject
private Foo injectedFoo;

}
```

Done ! Nothing else needed.